# How to treat 4 consecutive spaces as a single character?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, whitespace

I have written a TextArea that types 4 consecutive spaces whenever I press a certain key combination (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in my case), however, I am looking for a way to make the program treat them as if they're a single character, by which I mean that:

- the caret's position jumps from one end of the space sequence to the other if it moves towards it
- I can only select all of them at once
- if I press backspace and the caret is in front of them, all 4 get deleted at once

I've managed to complete the first two tasks by creating a caret position listener, but whenever I try to delete the 4 spaces, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error that redirects me to the listener, even though the code for that is written in a key event handler that checks if the key pressed is a backspace.

I'm only going to include the snippets of code that are relevant to the question, as the whole program is quite long:

```
textarea.caretPositionProperty().addListener((ob, old1, new1) -> {
    int oldi = old1.intValue();
    int newi = new1.intValue();
    if (oldi > newi && oldi > 3 && textarea.getText(oldi - 4, oldi).equals("    "))
        textarea.positionCaret(oldi - 4);

    if (oldi < newi && oldi < (textarea.getText().length() - 3) && textarea.getText(oldi, oldi + 4).equals("    "))
        textarea.positionCaret(oldi + 4);
});


textarea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
    int cp = textarea.getCaretPosition();
    if (e.isAltDown() && (e.getCode() == KeyCode.C)) {
        // Some other code
        textarea.positionCaret(cp + 4);
    }

    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE && areat.length() > 3)
        if (areat.substring(cp - 4, cp).equals("    "))
            textarea.setText(areat.substring(0, cp - 4) + areat.substring(cp));
});
```

To explain the `areat` variable: at one point, I thought that the problem might be caused by the `textarea.getText()` function, given that (presumably) it could either refer to the text before or after pressing backspace (e.g. either "Hello!" or "Hello"). Fortunately, I've already written a text property listener for a separate feature of the program, so I tried solving the problem by declaring a global variable (`areat`) and storing the old text there (which didn't work, needless to say):

```
textarea.textProperty().addListener((obs, old1, new1) -> {
    areat = old1;
    areatn = new1;
    // Some other code
});
```

How should I proceed from here? Is there a problem with the event handler or with the caret listener? Or maybe there is a specific method that has all the features mentioned above built-in?

Side note: I would prefer not switching to a `JTextArea`, as I've never worked with swing elements before.

EDIT: If you're an admin, please don't mark this question as solved, because I'm still looking for better answers, BUT I've managed to fix the issue by storing the **new** text of the text property listener in a global variable (`areatn`) instead of the old one, which I've used in both the event handler and the caret listener. Please do let me know if you've found a solution that's less bodged-in than mine.

EDIT 2: As @kleopatra pointed out in the comments, the TextFormatter class is much better equipped for this kind of situation than my listeners are.

Comment: I got no idea whether it's useful: use a tab character and a tab size of 4.

Comment: @OleV.V. If only... unfortunately, as far as I know, JavaFX does not provide a way to control the spacing of a tab character.

Comment: @Slaw it's work-in-progress: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/32

Comment: .. or maybe not: after re-reading, I have to admit that I don't quite understand the question ;) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after and why/how it doesn't behave as you want it to.

Comment: .. all that said: a TextFormatter is what you want to use (vs. listeners to any of the area's properties) - it get's every pending change to the input before it is applied and that change can be modified in every detail (like text, selection, caret position)

Comment: @javaion this is a way to strip all the carriage returns and tabs from a TextArea see if his works         String line = txaDiaryEntry.getText();
        strArray = line.split("\\s"); or look at this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076572/javafx-8-replace-text-in-textarea-and-maintain-formatting

Comment: @kleopatra Due to some other limitations imposed by the other parts of my code, I decided to use the TextFormatter just for deleting them all at once and I've kept the caret listener for the first two bullet points of my post. I could still implement them just fine in the TextFormatter as well, but it was quite a bit wordier than what I've written in the listener. I've gotten rid of the backspace event filter though, which basically did nothing, as it turned out. Thank you very much for your suggestion BTW!

Comment: repeating: textformatter is the way to go - you get all changes related to text _and_ caret _and_ selection in its filter before they are applied and are free to _change_ them! On the other hand: with a listener to any of them you have no information about the state of any the others. So don't, you'll build an unstable process. But then, it's your decision - you'll learn <g>

Comment: @kleopatra Just to clarify: when I wrote that comment, I had some issues with implementing the TextFormatter for the first two bullet points of the post because some other part of my code apparently made my caret jump to the very start of the text before returning where it was supposed to be, which meant that `change.getControlCaretPosition()` would return 0 immediately after pressing Alt+C. As a result, I would've had to write "if"s with a ton of conditions to compensate for that. Now that I've updated the code, I finally got rid of the caret listener. Thank you for your help once again.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to do this using a NavigationFilter. You would install one by calling the `setNavigationFilter()` method in `JTextComponent`. Here's what the JavaDocs say for NavigationFilter:

> `NavigationFilter` can be used to restrict where the cursor can be
> positioned. When the default cursor positioning actions attempt to
> reposition the cursor they will call into the `NavigationFilter`,
> assuming the `JTextComponent` has a non-null `NavigationFilter` set.
> In this manner the `NavigationFilter` can effectively restrict where
> the cursor can be positioned. Similarly `DefaultCaret` will call into
> the `NavigationFilter` when the user is changing the selection to
> further restrict where the cursor can be positioned.

You may be able to write a NavigationFilter that doesn't let the cursor be placed inside the four spaces. Typing an arrow key will move the caret across all four spaces, and selections will include the four spaces, so they will behave for the user as a single character. I've done this kind of thing and it's very reliable and isn't very hard.

Comment: the question is about javafx, not swing :)