# Javafx 8 replace text in textarea and maintain formatting

Tags: javafx, arraylist, textarea

We are trying to replace misspelled words in the TextArea and when the word is at the end of a line of text and has a carriage return the process is failing other misspelled words are replace as expected

> Example Text
>  Well are we reddy for production the spell test is here
>   but I fear the dictionary is the limiting factor ?
>
> Here is the carriage return test in the lin abov
>
> Hypenated words test slow-motion and lets not forget the date

Just after the misspelled word **abov** we have a carriage return in the ArrayList the text looks like this

> in, the, lin, abov

Because this misspelled word has no comma after it the replacement code also takes out the misspelled word Hypenated because the replacement code sees **"abov & Hypenated"** as being at the same Index

Result of running the replacement code

> Here is the carriage return test in the lin above words test

If this line of code `strArray = line.split(" ");`
is changed to this `strArray = line.split("\\s");` the issue goes away but so does the formatting in the TextArea all the carriage returns are deleted which is not a desired outcome

**The question is how to deal with the formatting issue and still replace the misspelled words?**

Side note this only happens when the misspelled word is at the end of a sentences for example the misspelled word **"lin"** will be replaced as desired
We have an excessive number of lines of code for this project so we are only posting the code that is causing the unsatisfactory results
We tried using just a String[ ] array with little or no success

```
@FXML
private void onReplace(){

    if(txtReplacementWord.getText().isEmpty()){
        txtMessage.setText("No Replacement Word");
        return;
    }

    cboMisspelledWord.getItems().remove(txtWordToReplace.getText());
    // Line Above Removes misspelled word from cboMisspelledWord 
    // ==========================================================
    String line = txaDiaryEntry.getText();
    strArray = line.split(" ");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strArray));
    for (int R = 0; R < list.size(); R++) {
        if(list.get(R).contains(txtWordToReplace.getText())){
            theIndex = R;
            System.out.println("## dex "+theIndex);//For testing
        }
    }
    System.out.println("list "+list);//For testing

    list.remove(theIndex);
    list.add(theIndex,txtReplacementWord.getText());

    sb = new StringBuilder(); 
for (String addWord : list) {
    sb.append(addWord);
    sb.append(" ");
}

    txaDiaryEntry.setText(sb.toString()); 
    txtMessage.setText("");
    txtReplacementWord.setText("");
    txtWordToReplace.setText("");
    cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().clear(); 
    cboMisspelledWord.requestFocus();

    // Code above replaces misspelled word with correct spelling in TextArea
    // =====================================================================
if(cboMisspelledWord.getItems().isEmpty()){
    onCheckSpelling();
} 
}
```

Comment: We saw your comment in the code I posted and tried to fix this issue but it is beyond my level of expertise! will use it in my scrabble app fabian produced some great code and YES where did =non-whitespace sequences in this case come from new one break out the search engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `split`. This way you loose the info about the content between the words. Instead create a `Pattern` matching words and make sure to also copy the substrings between matches. This way you don't loose any info there.

The following example replaces the replacement logic with simply looking for replacements in a `Map` for simplicity, but it should be sufficient to demonstrate the approach:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea(
            "Well are we reddy for production the spell test is here but I fear the dictionary is the limiting factor ?\n"
                    + "\n" + "Here is the carriage return test in the lin abov\n" + "\n"
                    + "Hypenated words test slow-motion and lets not forget the date");

    Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
    replacements.put("lin", "line");
    replacements.put("abov", "above");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+"); // pattern matching words (=non-whitespace sequences in this case)
    Button button = new Button("Replace");
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        String text = textArea.getText();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int lastEnd = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int startIndex = matcher.start();
            if (startIndex > lastEnd) {
                // add missing whitespace chars
                sb.append(text.substring(lastEnd, startIndex));
            }

            // replace text, if necessary
            String group = matcher.group();
            String result = replacements.get(group);
            sb.append(result == null ? group : result);

            lastEnd = matcher.end();
        }
        sb.append(text.substring(lastEnd));
        textArea.setText(sb.toString());
    });

    final Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(textArea, button));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Works great removed the button part and the code in a OnActionEvent I am still trying to wrap my head around the Pattern.compile)"\\S+") line of code guess I need to read about no white space matches Your Answer means a lot to me Thank You

Comment: The character classes are defined in the javadoc for `Pattern`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html (`\S` is the complement of `\s` and the `+` simply means "a positive number of those" which works in this case, since the matcher is greedy).